# How do I display the newly added state object in the page without page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am displaying the properties(recipe title, image url) of objects from a `state`. These objects are from `mongodb`. I have written below my current code flow.

1. Create empty array state variable called `initialRecipes` via `const [initialRecipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);`
2. Load the recipes from db and push each object to state array via `setRecipes([...initialRecipes, response.data.message[i]])`
3. Render the recipes on the page via `return()` and loop through the `initialRecipes` variable via `.map` function
4. Add new recipe to the state variable on form submission and show the newly added recipe automatically on the page - ***This is my current problem***

**Recipes.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// code snippet

const Recipes = () => {
  const [formFieldValue, setFormFieldValues] = useState({
    recipe_name: '',
    image_url: '',
    buttonText: 'Submit'
  });
  const {recipe_name, image_url, buttonText} = formFieldValue;
  const [initialRecipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAllRecipes();
  }, []);


  const loadAllRecipes = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/recipe`,
    })
    .then(response => {
      for (let i=0; i<response.data.message.length; i++) {

        // save each object to state array
        setRecipes([
          ...initialRecipes,
          response.data.message[i]
        ])
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // code snippet
    });
  };

  // save form input changes to state
  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setFormFieldValues({...formFieldValue, [name]: event.target.value});
  };


  // form fields snippet
  const addRecipeForm = () => (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="text-muted">Recipe name</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control recipe-form-input" value={recipe_name} onChange={handleChange('recipe_name')} />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="text-muted">Image url</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control recipe-form-input" value={image_url} onChange={handleChange('image_url')} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );


  // add new recipe in the form
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/recipe`
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Recipe is saved successfully!', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(error.response.data.error);
    });
  };

  // show add recipe form and display all recipes using a loop
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="row">
        {addRecipeForm()}
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <h2 className="title text-center">List of Recipes</h2>

        <div className="all-recipes-list ">
          {
            initialRecipes.map((recipe, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index} className="wrapper">
                    <img className="image" src={recipe.image_url} />
                    <a className="link" href="#">
                      <h4 className="title">{recipe.recipe_name}</h4>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                );
            })
          }
        </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Recipes;
```

**Problem:** How can I show the newly added Recipe via `API(saved in MongoDB)` endpoint in the `<div className="all-recipes-list"></div>` element of the page without page refresh?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `setRecipes` inside a loop which is going to queue as many state updates as there are items. Compose the new state once and *then* call setRecipes once. You're also not using a callback in `setRecipes` so a closure is created over `initialRecipes`. Remove the loop and simply call `setRecipes(prev => [...prev, ...response.data.message]);`

Comment: @pilchard I am quite a newbie. Should I replace the `initialRecipes` loop in return function with `setRecipes(prev => [...prev, ...response.data.message])` ?

Comment: Yes, for a start. It will yield more predictable results with fewer renders (React does batch setState calls, but here it is very straightforward to make a single call. See: [Queueing a Series of State Updates](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates))

Comment: @pilchard I am able to solve the issue about displaying the new object without page reload. I will deal with the looping issue later.  You can check my answer below.Thank you so much for your guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue now. I just need to add `setRecipes([...initialRecipes, newRecipe]);` inside `const handleSubmit = event => ();`

```
  // add new recipe in the form
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/recipe`
    })
    .then(response => {
      let newRecipe = JSON.parse(response.config.data); // convert new recipe from string to object
      console.log('Recipe is saved successfully!', response);

      setRecipes([...initialRecipes, newRecipe]); // push new recipe to the state
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(error.response.data.error);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

After the post request, fetch the data using get request or simply use the `react query` to fetch data using the `useQuery` as it does what you want
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/recipe`
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Recipe is saved successfully!', response);
      axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/recipe`,
     })
     .then(response => {
       for (let i=0; i<response.data.message.length; i++) {

         // save each object to state array
         setRecipes([
           ...initialRecipes,
           response.data.message[i]
         ])
       }
     })
     .catch(error => {
       // code snippet
     });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(error.response.data.error);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I posted my solution above now.